# Contactless javacard security implementation with NFC device

Tags: nfc, javacard

Consider a employee using a NFC android device to report his location by reading a contactless javacard fixed to a wall accessible to everyone.

1. Employee scans the javacard with the smarthphone, sends only a timestamp
2. The contactless javacard receives the timestamp, adds it's UID and encrypts with stored publickey and sends it back
3. Android receives the encrypted message and relays it to a server which holds the private key, (may stay on queue due to lack of connectivity)
4. Server decrypts the message and checks if the information is valid and reports back.

Would a JCOP31 Java Card with dual interface be a good enough match ?

The whole idea is to avoid card/tag cloning at all costs.

I have never done any sort of javacard implementation and would love to hear your feedback on this sequence of events and architecture.

Comment: The problem is that your javacard applet has no access to its HW physical UID...

Comment: It would have to store the UID in EEPROM in some prepersonalisation phase of its lifecycle.

Comment: could you expand on the pre personalization phase ?

Comment: Well, you would have to read the UID by some trusted device before you put the contactless card into the wild and upload the UID to the persistent memory (EEPROM) of your Javacard applet, because you cannot access UID (which is a HW property) from your applet (because it cannot get out of its SW sandbox).

Comment: You should also switch the roles of public and private keys. You do not need encryption, you need a digital signature. So the private part should be stored in Javacard and the public part in the server.

Comment: thank you for your help. Is the key management done with Global Platform ?

Comment: Yes, you can put the key into the applet during the install phase of your applet loading. It is the easiest and safest way.

Comment: Warning: it seems that in your protocol anybody can ask for a signature and that any time stamp may be accepted. Just a tiny side note :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A signature is actually sufficient for this usecase as you do only need an authentic timestamp but no encryption I suppose.
2. Oncard Key Generation is the proper way to do this.
3. UID is available for JCOP inside the jc-applet(jcopx, you will need to ask NXP which version is required for this feature).

Comment: For this specific use case I should maybe store an existing private key in the card, instead of generating them oncard, right?

Comment: No you should  generate the key pair during installation and send out the public key as a response. This way the private key exists only on the card and never leaves it. Otherwise you have to ensure that the private key is safely deleted after import into the card on your key generation device

Comment: ah ok I see, during installation I'll get the public key and save it later in the server, in order to verify if the messages are valid.

Comment: Yes (this post needs 15 char )

Comment: Seems a good and valid approach to me, I'll mark it as answered. Thank you

Comment: If you're going to have a device specific key, you might as well put the UID (or other identifier) in it at that time as well, if you want to stay Java Card compatible.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes you mean that I should store the UID in the EEPROM during pre personalization phase?

Comment: I think he means you have to exchange information anyway in the personalization of the card :either export public key or import private key, so you can also put in the uid there because jcopx package is only compliant to cards that support it. In fact i think you can put in any kind of identifier,even a char string and just include it in the signature. So you sign timestamp and an self formatted id, so you don't have restrictions of uid.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant.